# How to redirect to another page after clicking 5 images

Tags: jquery, image, function, redirect, click

I want the user to be redirected to another page after they click the five images (with ids "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4" and "image5"). I'm not quite sure why this code isn't working. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$(function() {
    $change1 = false;
    $change2 = false;
    $change3 = false;
    $change4 = false;
    $change5 = false;

    $("#image1").click(function() {
        $change1 = true;
    });
    $("#image2").click(function() {
        $change2 = true;
    });
    $("#image3").click(function() {
        $change3 = true;
    });
    $("#image4").click(function() {
        $change4 = true;
    });
    $("#image5").click(function() {
        $change5 = true;
    });

    if ($change1 && $change2 && $change3 && $change4 && $change5) {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're only checking the condition once. I've dealt with this exact problem several times while teachings kids to program.

Put the `if ($change1...)` block into a function, then call this function in each `.click()` handler.

Comment: Could do without the belittling sarcasm but your answer worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is a much shorter way to do this:

```
var hitFive=0;

$('img[id^=image]').click(function(){
    hitFive++;
    if(hitFive>=5){
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that checks and redirects needs to be called in every click handler. You could make your code much shorter as follows:

```
$(function() {
    var changes = [ false, false, false, false, false ];

    $("[id^=image]").click(function() {
        var n = this.id.split('').pop();
        if( $.isNumeric( n ) && n > 0 && n < 6 ) {
            changes[ n - 1 ] = true;
        }
        checkGo();
    });

    function checkGo() {
        if (changes[0] && changes[1] && changes[2] && changes[3] && changes[4]) {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this :

```
$("#image1").click(function() {
    $change1 = true;
    test5Click();
});

$("#image2").click(function() {
    $change2 = true;
    test5Click();
  });

 $("#image3").click(function() {
    $change3 = true;
    test5Click();
});

$("#image4").click(function() {
    $change4 = true;
    test5Click();
});

$("#image5").click(function() {
    $change5 = true;
    test5Click();
});

function test5Click() {
if ($change1 && $change2 && $change3 && $change4 && $change5) {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
}}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    change1 = false;
    change2 = false;
    change3 = false;
    change4 = false;
    change5 = false;

    $('#image1').bind('click', function(){
        change1 = true;
        update();
    });
    $('#image2').bind('click', function(){
        change2 = true;
        update();
    });
    $('#image3').bind('click', function(){
        change3 = true;
        update();
    });
    $('#image3').bind('click', function(){
        change3 = true;
        update();
    });
    $('#image4').bind('click', function(){
        change4 = true;
        update();
    });
    $('#image5').bind('click', function(){
        change5 = true;
        update();
    });
});

function update(){

    if(change1 && change2 && change3 && change4 && change5){
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
}
```

Event handlers should be inside the $(document).ready(...) and you have to check whether all images were clicked each time a value changes (= an image is clicked)

Comment: Whoops, messed with some variable names. Edited and should work now.

Answer (score 0):

your if statement is called only once, when the document is ready.

you should encapsulate it in a function and call that every time an image is clicked, like so :

```
....

$("#image1").click(function() {
    $change1 = true;
    checkClickedImages();
});

....

function checkClickedImages() {
  if ($change1 && $change2 && $change3 && $change4 && $change5) {
      window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
  }
};
```